# While rendering the output of summernote editor it shows with the raw html

Tags: reactjs, summernote

I used the summernote editor for the input and the input text is formatted in the editor. However, when I rendered the output of editor in html, It renders with the html tags for the format I have chosen.

See the image below for the better understanding my problem.

[image]

Source Code

http://pastebin.com/k6wKY3ny

```
var QuestionList = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.qlist.map(function (option) {
                    return (
                        <div key={option.question}>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div className='col-md-10'>
                                    {option.question}{option.detail}
                                </div>
                                <div className='col-md-2' style={{
                                    'text-align':
                                        'right',
                                }}>
                                    <span className='editicon' ref='edit'><i className='fa fa-pencil'
                                                                             title='Edit Question'></i></span>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span className='deleteicon'><i className='fa fa-trash-o'
                                                                    title='Delete Question'></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-offset-1' id={option.question}></div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var QuestionForm = React.createClass({
    saveQuestion: function () {
        var question = this.refs.question.getDOMNode();
// var detail = this.refs.detail.getDOMNode();
        var content = $('#qdetail').summernote('code');
// var content = $('textarea[name="detail"]').html($('#qdetail').val());

        questionlist.push({question: question.value, detail: content});

        React.render(
            <QuestionList qlist={questionlist}/>, document.getElementById('questionlist'));
        React.render(
            <AnswerForm id={question.value}/>, document.getElementById('answerform'));
        question.value = '';
        $('#qdetail').summernote('destroy');
        document.getElementById('questionform').innerHTML = ''
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        $('#qdetail').summernote({
            height: 250, // set editor height
            minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
            maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
            focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
            toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style', 'fontsize']], // no style button
                // ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],

                // ['color', ['color']],
                // ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['para', ['ol', 'ul']],
                // ['height', ['height']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'table', 'hr']], // no insert buttons
                //['table', ['table']], // no table button
                ['help', ['help']],
            ],
            htmlMode: true,
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: 'text/html'

        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="form-group">
                    Question:
                    <input type='text' className="form-control" name='question' ref='question'/>

                    Detail:
                    <div id='qdetail'></div>

                </p>
                <button onClick={this.saveQuestion} className="btn btn-primary">Save Question</button>
            </div>


        );
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show some working code??

Comment: I have added the link to source code.